# arduino : If AT+CIPSEND is used and a value is entered, nothing can be returned after SEND OK is output

Tags: php, esp8266

```
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","172.30.1.51",80

CONNECT

OK
AT+CIPSEND=63


OK
> 

busy s...

Recv 63 bytes

SEND OK
```

I am checking whether the code I entered to test the ESP-01 Wi-Fi module is uploaded to the database.

I entered the code below, and SEND OK was printed on my serial monitor.

```
GET /process.php?tem=20.7&radi=5.6&dust=11.3&hum=213.1 HTTP/1.0
```

However, in the guide I saw, it is written that SEND OK is output unconditionally,
and that the value is delivered only when '+IPD, 243:HTTP/1.1 200OK' is displayed.

But I only get SEND OK. What should I do?

I've tried changing the number of bytes passed in AT+CIPSEND several times.

Comment: it is 63 without the invisible line ending characters (they now cause the busy message) and the server waits for them. use `AT+CIPSEND=65`.

Comment: The result does not change....